# Best way to manage dynamics documents objects in C# (official driver)

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I searching the best ways to manage extensibles schemas in C# using a BsonObject that can be extended without construct a object class that hold a definition of each key.

The object is create a Document storage that can be extended using a configuration file key,value,type from a definition. I haved used in another project a BsonArray storage but is not pratical and indexs are not very usefull in our case. The object is build a object like a list of dynamics keys values for a best indexing exposition and query.

Thanks.

```
//BsonArray method:
    new BsonKeys()
    {
       Key = key,
       Value = item,
       Type = type
    }
    //--------------------------------------------
    //get a cursor like : List<BsonKeys> list
    //--------------------------------------------
    //save method like:
    //.Set("DynamicKeyValues", new BsonArray(list.Select(x => (BsonValue)x.ToBsonDocument())))
    Document result :
    {
        ID:"some _id",
        StaticKey:"Some static",
        ...   
        DynamicKeyValues
        [
            {Key="keyname1" , value="Value1", type="String"},
            {...},
            {Key="keynameN" , value="ValueN", type="String"}    
        ]       
    } 
    //-------------------------------------------

    //Searching like :
    {
        ID:"some _id",
        StaticKey:"Some static",
        ...   
        DynamicKeyValues
        {
          Key:value,
          Key2:Value2,
          ...
          KeyN:valueN   
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to increase you search performance, you should to use duplicate data for search. for example: to separate your data by "key". try to use different storage collection for each "key".

Something like this:

```
//for key is Location
LocationCollection
{
    Value: value
    // reference to root entity
    ID:"some _id",
    StaticKey:"Some static",
}

//for key is Name of person
FullNameCollection
{
    Value: value
    // reference to root entity
    ID:"some _id",
    StaticKey:"Some static",
}
```